# Empty set under existential quantifier

Tags: quantifiers

Let $U = \{s_1, s_2, s_\cdots, s_n\}$ be the universal set and $A = \{a_1, a_2, a_3,\cdots, a_m\}$ is the set under consideration.

Now, I am proving $\forall_{x \in \{\}} p(x) = T$  as follows

$$\forall_{x \in A} p(x) = \forall_{x \in u} (x \in A \implies p(x))  $$
$$= (s_1 \in A \implies p(s_1)) \land (s_2 \in A \implies p(s_2)) \land \cdots (s_n \in A \implies p(s_n))$$

Hence if $A = \{\}$, then premise in every conditional statement becomes false and the result will be true.

But it is not working to prove $\exists_{x \in \{\}} p(x) = T$;

How to prove it?

Comment: $\exists_{x \in \{\}} p(x)$ is $\exists x (x \in \{ \} \land p(x))$.

Comment: What will be the expansion for $\exists_{x \in A} p(x)$

Comment: Like this

$$\forall_{x \in A} p(x) = \forall_{x \in u} (x \in A \implies p(x))  $$
$$= (s_1 \in A \implies p(s_1)) \land (s_2 \in A \implies p(s_2)) \land \cdots (s_n \in A \implies p(s_n))$$

Just to replace $\land$ by $\lor$?

Comment: $\forall$ is like a conjunction while $\exists$ is like a disjunction. Thus $\exists x P(x)$ will be : $P(s_1) \lor P(s_2) \lor \ldots \lor P(s_n)$.

Comment: So, is it true that

$$\exists{x \in A} p(x) = \exists{x \in u} (x \in A \implies p(x))  $$
$$= (s_1 \in A \implies p(s_1)) \lor (s_2 \in A \implies p(s_2)) \lor \cdots (s_n \in A \implies p(s_n))$$

Comment: NO; as said above $\exists_{x \in A}P(x)$ is $\exists x (x \in A \land P(x))$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This won't work because $\exists x\in\{\},p(x)$ is false.

Like Mauro says in the first comment,
$
    \exists x\in\{\},p(x)
$
is syntactic sugar for $\exists x , (x\in\{\} \wedge p(x))$.  But $x\in\{\}$ can never be true, so $x\in\{\} \wedge p(x)$ is never true, so $\exists x , (x\in\{\} \wedge p(x))$ is false.

You seem hung up on expanding quantification to the individual elements of a set.  That's not necessary, and seems to limit you logically to a finite universal set.  But these statements are true irrespective of the cardinality of $U$.